# How to use mocha test external javascript resources?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm trying to run a mocha test to test the function in external js file, but when I try to run mocha test, it gives me nothing, meaning something wrong of my test.js
If I'm test an function internally inside test.js, it works.
this is the reference guide how I generate the below code, http://dailyjs.com/2011/12/08/mocha/

This is the js need to be test (the relative path to test.js is `../../scripts/main`)

```
function add(a,b){
    return a+b;
}

module.exports.add = add;
```

This is my test.js

```
/* global describe, it */
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var assert = chai.assert;
    var expect = chai.expect;
    var should = chai.should();
    var add = require('../../scripts/main').add;
    describe('test1', function(){
        it('should return 3 when add 1 and 2', function(done){
          assert.equal(3, add(1,2));
          done();
        });
    });
})();
```

---

with @c089 's help, here is the working script :)

```
/* global describe, it */
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var add = require('./main').add;
    var assert = require("assert");
    describe('test1', function(){
        it('should return 3 when add 1 and 2', function(done){
          assert.equal(5, add(1,2));
          done();
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: I would expect this code to throw because `chai` is not required. What do you mean by "try to run mocha test" and "gives me nothing", exactly?

Comment: @c089 it gives me >> 0 passed! (0.00s), means it not running my js file

Comment: Try passing it the file to execute as first argument, or the test directory combined with the `--recursive`.

Comment: @c089 I'm using grunt mocha, don't think it comes with --recursive, what do you mean passing it the file to execute as first argument

Comment: Try running mocha yourself from a terminal, e.g.:
`$ mocha --recursive ./test`

Comment: You're right: From a grunt task you'l probably use a pattern with `**` instead of a recursive option.

Comment: I'm done to run mocha --recursive gives me Error: Cannot find module 'main'

Comment: That's better, you have errors now ;) Seems you need to fix the path to your main module in the require call now. Good luck :)

Comment: @c089 yap, I've fix the path, but how i can define `var assert = chai.assert;`, it tells me chai is not defined...

Comment: Told you so ;) You have to require the `chai` module and assign it to a variable before you can access. Maybe the [modules documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) could be handy.

Comment: @c089 I figure it out, thank you so much

Comment: @c089 but a strange things come out, mocha directly test works, but use grunt mocha, it still not working :( -,-!